# How to bind two scatter charts in WPF (MVVM, ViewModel-First)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

How to bind scatter series points from one window to another window having same scatter chart at runtime?

I have a resulted scatter chart points in one window, and I want to perform different operation on the same points in another window.

thanks in advance

Comment: Add some code to the question. It will be really difficult for people to help with this otherwise.

Comment: Why can't you bind the datasource of the two scatter charts to the same result set?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that data source is loaded from a .csv file. Scatter chart is resulted after Multi-Dimensional Scaling (MDS) algorithm, where we can see data points of one cluster close to each other. I want to achieve same cluster representation by applying k-means on MDS chart. MDS viewmodel/class fills the chart initially from csv file, before generating clusters. How can I get the data representation from- 1) csv file and 2) updated MDS in KmeansView? Do I have write the same logic from MDS view model/class in Kmeans view model/class to get initially 1) ? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVVM, you can bind the source of your scatter charts to a property in a viewmodel/class.

For example:

```
private Series _plotVariable;

public Series PlotVariable
{
   get
   {
       return _plotVariable;
   }
   set
   {
       _plotVariable = value;
   }
}
```

If you bind the source of your scatter charts to PlotVariable, when your class sets the value of _plotVariable, the scatter charts will update.

Comment: Hi, I want to integrate k-means clustering algorithm in one tool. The tool already has different implemented clustering algorithms such as hierarchical clustering algorithm, multi-dimensional scaling, etc. The tool imports a .csv file containing data values and their distances  . 
After loading the file, we can see the data representation for each algorithm in corresponding window, and apply the algorithm to achieve clusters.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that data source is loaded from a .csv file. Scatter chart is resulted after Multi-Dimensional Scaling (MDS) algorithm, where we can see data points of one cluster close to each other. I want to achieve same cluster representation by applying k-means on MDS chart. 
MDS viewmodel/class fills the chart initially from csv file, before generating clusters.  
How can I get the data representation from- 
1) csv file and  2) updated  MDS  in KmeansView? 
Do I have write the same logic from MDS view model/class in Kmeans view model/class to get initially 1) ? 
thanks!